# Python Regex how to remove all words except starting or ending with $

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I want to remove all digits except digits starting with $ or ending with $.
Below is the sample text

```
"\\r\\n-MacBook 2018 $4000 \\r\\n-Apple watch S3\\r\\n-11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods"
```

I have tried below code to clean text.

```
import re
text = "\\r\\n-MacBook 2018 $4000 \\r\\n-Apple watch S3\\r\\n-11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods"
print(text)
text = re.sub(r'(?:\\+[rn]|\s)+',' ',text).strip()
print(text)
text=re.sub(r'[^\w\s\$]',' ',text)
print(text)

\r\n-MacBook 2018 $4000 \r\n-Apple watch S3\r\n-11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods
-MacBook 2018 $4000 -Apple watch S3 -11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods
 MacBook 2018 $4000  Apple watch S3  11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods
```

The answer should be
`$4000 5000$ $1000 200$`

Eventually I want to sum all of the numbers with $ sign. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: wouldnt s3 get removed?

Comment: So what is it that you want to do? Remove non-monetary *numbers*? Find monetary numbers and add them up? Or both?

Comment: This is yet another case of trying to wrangle regexes where a simple loop using `split` would have been working long ago.

Comment: Yes sorry my bad! S3 should be removed. @JoranBeasley

Comment: Just iterate in a loop over split text and concatenate what's needed, skip what's not needed.

Comment: @InSync Yes I want to first remove non monetary numbers. I  have the solution of summing them afterwards.

Comment: @TimRoberts  I am not sure if this is an efficient way. I have rows in millions.

Comment: ```(\$)\d{1,}|\d{1,}(\$)``` will find your legit prices, you can save them in a dict and put keys in string instead, and then put back after removing everything that has numbers.

Comment: In fairness, what you're saying now is quite different from the specification you started with.

Comment: Do you actually want to include the `$` in your matches? Seems like that would add complexity later when you're trying to perform mathematical operations on them. I would suggest using lookaround https://regex101.com/r/qB6zjE/1

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer.

```
import re
text = "\\r\\n-MacBook 2018 $4000 \\r\\n-Apple watch S3\\r\\n-11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods"
print(text)
text = re.sub(r'(?:\\+[rn]|\s)+',' ',text).strip()
print(text)
text=re.sub(r'[^\w\s\$]',' ',text)
print(text)
amount = re.findall(r'\$\d+|\d+\$', text)
print(amount)
print(sum(int(x.replace('$', '')) for x in amount))

\r\n-MacBook 2018 $4000 \r\n-Apple watch S3\r\n-11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods
-MacBook 2018 $4000 -Apple watch S3 -11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods
 MacBook 2018 $4000  Apple watch S3  11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods
['$4000', '5000$', '$1000', '200$']
10200
```

Comment: That's AN answer, but it's not the best answer.  Doesn't the `amount =` line do what you need all by itself?

Comment: Yes I wanted to sum of all amounts. By the way let me know if you any better way. @TimRoberts

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing, you can just match 1+ digits starting or ending with a `$` and then sum the result of re.findall

```
(?<=\$)\d+|\d+(?=\$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\$)\d+` Assert `$` to the left and match 1+ digits
- `|` Or
- `\d+(?=\$)` Match 1+ digits and assert `$` to the right

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SVsuDl/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xXRLuy)

```
import re

s = "\\r\\n-MacBook 2018 $4000 \\r\\n-Apple watch S3\\r\\n-11 5000$ 1000Islands iphone$1000 200$airpods"
regex = r"(?<=\$)\d+|\d+(?=\$)"
res = sum([int(i) for i in re.findall(regex, s)])
print(res)
```

Output

```
10200
```

---

Another option is using 2 capture groups and the you can loop the result of re.finditer checking if group 1 exists, else take the group 2 value.

```
\$(\d+)|(\d+)\$
```